# Why does running two Queue listeners on different CPUs take longer to process than one?

Tags: java, queue, jms

I have 2 programs and 3 CPUs. One is a program that does two things. First, it sends about 60k messages to a JMS Queue (XMLQueue). The second thing it does is listen to a different JMS Queue (ResultQueue) and extracts the returned data and processes it. This program runs on CPU 1.

The second program is a validator program. It receives messages from XMLQueue, does some validations and then sends the result to the ResultQueue. Each time this program receives a new message, it processes that message in a different thread (up to a maximum amount of threads running at once obviously). And if the maximum is running, it waits for one to die before receiving a new message. In order to improve performance, I am attempting to run this program on 2 CPUs, figuring if each CPU does half the work, it should cut total processing from about 3 hours to 1.5, or even less if I get it running on 3 or 4 machines.

My problem is that when the validator program on only one CPU, it takes about 200 seconds to process 1000 messages. When I add in a second CPU, it takes 500 seconds!! I figure there has got be something about Queues that I am not understanding correctly for the time to increase when I use more memory and more processors to do the job. Any ideas?

Here is the code where the listening is done. The session is set to auto acknowledge.

```
public void listen() {
    if(closed){
        throw new IllegalStateException("cannot listen to a closed connection");
    }
    try{
        boolean listening=true;
        while(listening){
            Message msg = mc.receive();
            System.out.println("Received message " + ++count );
            if (msg instanceof TextMessage){
                TextMessage tmsg = (TextMessage) msg;
                String xml = tmsg.getText();

                DataParser parser = new XmlParser("paths.properties");

                synchronized(tm){
                    while(tm.isFull()){
                        try{

                            tm.wait();

                        }catch(InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    new Executor(xml, tm,parser,responder);
                    tm.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            else if (msg instanceof ObjectMessage){
                closeConnection();
                closed = true;
                listening=false;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: How do you assign CPUs to programs? Do you use hardware virtualization solutions like Oracle VirtualBox or Parallels Virtuozzo Containers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean be assign... I don't really "assign" anything. I just run the 'validation' program on 3-4 machines and run the 'sending' program on another.

Answer (score 0):

Messaging is already parallel "by nature" somehow.

So try to remove your multi threading code, and replace it

- With multiple *programs* instances, using a simple listener on a queue.
- With one program using multiple *threads*. Again each thread listens on the queue. The difference to your approach is that there are multiple listeners upfront.

Both approaches eliminate the need to manage (create/synchronize) threads *in* the listener *during* processing, because the processing threads already exist when a message arrives.

Comment: There is only one listening thread. I ensured this by using the msg.receive() method rather than the MessageListener interface. The multi-threading aspect is limited based on the tm.isFull() method. While the max number of threads are running, the program will not receive any messages until one of those threads dies.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out there was not an issue with the posted code. the validations that I was processing were making calls to a database. since i had multiple threads and multiple machines making calls to the same database, the performance was reduced significantly. fixed the problem by caching the needed tables before hand on each machine.